# Can we get data from session storage on separate ports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, session-storage

session is set on port 8080, so we have problem getting data on 3000,
is it possible to get session data on this port?

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('username')) {
   ...code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only way to access that is with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) throught an iframe and some sort of message protocol